# Launch host and target crosscompiling builds inside CMake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

Is there a way to configure CMake such that a single `make` command will launch both host and target builds? I have a project that is meant to be run on a target platform but requires some generated data from a `generator` that needs to run on the host platform (PC). From CMake's documentation and looking around, I need a 2 pass build - first host to create the generator then the target crosscompiling build. My question is specifically how to launch the 2-pass build with a single `make` command through CMake configurations **(not using an external bash or python script)**.

Things I know

1. CMake doesn't allow changing toolchain within a single build
2. Almost solutions like: [How to instruct CMake to use the build architecture compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173840/how-to-instruct-cmake-to-use-the-build-architecture-compiler) Which is fine except I need to skip the 2nd step of using an external script
3. How to separate what's run during crosscompiling or not [cmake - compile natively and crosscompile the same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410880/cmake-compile-natively-and-crosscompile-the-same-code)
4. It is supposedly possible to launch multiple CMake builds using CMake [How to make CMake targeting multiple plattforms in a single build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365513/how-to-make-cmake-targeting-multiple-plattforms-in-a-single-build)

Comment: You can always bend CMake and `make` to basically do whatever you want. I would just question if it is worth the effort and if anybody looking at your solution is still able to understand the inner workings and/or to find possible problems. For example just think about the `stdout`/`stderr` output in one of the possible scenarios where you always go for crosscompiling and inside do call `cmake` again for a host build via `add_custom_command()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Let's say you have an `buildTool` sub-directory for the host build tools:

**buildTools\CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(BuildTools)

add_executable(genfoo genfoo.cpp)
```

Then you could have a main:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    set(_genfoo "bin/genfoo${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}")
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${_genfoo}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} 
                    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Release"
                    -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE:PATH="${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
                    -B"bin"
                    -H"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/buildTools"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build bin --config Release
    )
else()
    set(_genfoo genfoo)
    add_subdirectory(buildTools)
endif()

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT foo.h
    COMMAND ${_genfoo}
    DEPENDS ${_genfoo}
)

add_executable(bar bar.cpp foo.h)
target_include_directories(bar PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

**References**

- [How to instruct CMake to use the build architecture compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173840/how-to-instruct-cmake-to-use-the-build-architecture-compiler)

Comment: Great! Could you elaborate on the `-B` and `-H` options and the `bin` param to `--build`? Can't find it in `cmake --help`. Where are they documented?

Comment: However I found a problem: `${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX}"` is the current suffix. When compiling for windows on linux this will be (IMO) ".exe" but the generated file file not have that suffix as it is compiled on linux.